# When I click on a value in the search bar list, I want it to go to the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, search

389 / 5.000
Çeviri sonuçları
Hello, I have a search box problem. This problem is as follows;

Search box working logic is based on javascript file. When the letter "a" is clicked, I want to redirect to that page with a link when any of them is selected. but the link is only visible when hovering over the letter a. I didn't know how to pull slugs with a different array. I would really appreciate if you can help.

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {


  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
     
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
 
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items text-primary");
     
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
     
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      
      
      
      
      
      
        var s1=arr[i].substr(0, val.length);
        var s2=val;
        
        
        var string = s1;
        var letters = { "İ": "i", "I": "ı", "Ş": "ş", "Ğ": "ğ", "Ü": "ü", "Ö": "ö", "Ç": "ç", "A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c", "D": "d", "E": "e", "F": "f", "G": "g", "H": "h", "J": "j", "K": "k", "L": "l", "M": "m", "N": "n", "O": "o", "P": "p", "R": "r", "S": "s", "T": "t", "U": "u", "V": "v", "Y": "y", "Z": "z"};
        var s1 = string.replace(/(([İIŞĞÜÇÖABCDEFGHJKLMNOPRSTUVYZ]))/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; });
        
        
        var string = s2;
        var letters = { "İ": "i", "I": "ı", "Ş": "ş", "Ğ": "ğ", "Ü": "ü", "Ö": "ö", "Ç": "ç", "A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c", "D": "d", "E": "e", "F": "f", "G": "g", "H": "h", "J": "j", "K": "k", "L": "l", "M": "m", "N": "n", "O": "o", "P": "p", "R": "r", "S": "s", "T": "t", "U": "u", "V": "v", "Y": "y", "Z": "z" };
        var s2 = string.replace(/(([İIŞĞÜÇÖABCDEFGHJKLMNOPRSTUVYZ]))/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; });
        

        
        if (s1 == s2) {
        
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
       
          b.innerHTML = '<a href="https://universitenitanit.com/">' + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + '</a>';
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
       
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
         
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
           
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      
        currentFocus++;
      
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        
        currentFocus--;
      
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
        
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
   
    if (!x) return false;
 
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
 
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
   
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}
var cities = ["İstanbul","Albania","Algeria","Isparta","Şırnak","Çanakkale","Denizli","Bitlis","Düzce","Ankara","Adana","Eskişehir","İstanbul Teknik Üniversitesi","Marmara Üniversitesi"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("searchInput"), cities);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control form-input"
                id="searchInput" placeholder="Şehir veya Üniversite Ara...">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you looked at jQuery UI Autocomplete? it has an `onSelect` method that might help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you're asking. Sounds like you want to display a tooltip when you hover over the link?

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {


  var currentFocus;

  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
     
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
 
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items text-primary");
     
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
     
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      
      
      
      
      
      
        var s1=arr[i].substr(0, val.length);
        var s2=val;
        
        
        var string = s1;
        var letters = { "İ": "i", "I": "ı", "Ş": "ş", "Ğ": "ğ", "Ü": "ü", "Ö": "ö", "Ç": "ç", "A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c", "D": "d", "E": "e", "F": "f", "G": "g", "H": "h", "J": "j", "K": "k", "L": "l", "M": "m", "N": "n", "O": "o", "P": "p", "R": "r", "S": "s", "T": "t", "U": "u", "V": "v", "Y": "y", "Z": "z"};
        var s1 = string.replace(/(([İIŞĞÜÇÖABCDEFGHJKLMNOPRSTUVYZ]))/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; });
        
        
        var string = s2;
        var letters = { "İ": "i", "I": "ı", "Ş": "ş", "Ğ": "ğ", "Ü": "ü", "Ö": "ö", "Ç": "ç", "A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c", "D": "d", "E": "e", "F": "f", "G": "g", "H": "h", "J": "j", "K": "k", "L": "l", "M": "m", "N": "n", "O": "o", "P": "p", "R": "r", "S": "s", "T": "t", "U": "u", "V": "v", "Y": "y", "Z": "z" };
        var s2 = string.replace(/(([İIŞĞÜÇÖABCDEFGHJKLMNOPRSTUVYZ]))/g, function(letter){ return letters[letter]; });
        

        
        if (s1 == s2) {
        
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
       
          b.innerHTML = '<a class="tooltip" href="https://universitenitanit.com/">' + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + '<span class="tooltipText">https://universitenitanit.com/</span></a>';
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
       
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>"; 
          
         
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
           
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
          
        }
      }
  });

  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      
        currentFocus++;
      
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        
        currentFocus--;
      
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
        
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
   
    if (!x) return false;
 
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
 
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
   
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}
var cities = ["İstanbul","Albania","Algeria","Isparta","Şırnak","Çanakkale","Denizli","Bitlis","Düzce","Ankara","Adana","Eskişehir","İstanbul Teknik Üniversitesi","Marmara Üniversitesi"];

autocomplete(document.getElementById("searchInput"), cities);
```

```css
.tooltip{
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip .tooltipText {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 200px;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltipText {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control form-input"
                id="searchInput" placeholder="Şehir veya Üniversite Ara...">
```